# mySQL adjacency list model : Always retrieve parent and children/siblings

Tags: mysql

I’m using mySQL to create and adjacency list model type of table. I have only one level, that is a parent with children, like this:

```
TABLE article (article_id, title, parent_article_id)
```

Here’s a sample data

```
article_id title    parent_article_id
-------------------------------------
45         abc      null
61         mm       null
59         hgg      61
62         sef      61
67         wsr      61
```

Basically, I want to retrieve the parent and children/siblings depending of the where clause.

So, if I select an `article_id`, let’s say 59, I want to return:

```
article_id title    parent_article_id
-------------------------------------
61         mm       null
59         hgg      61
62         sef      61
67         wsr      61
```

That is the parent/top of the node (61), and chidren/sibings (59, 62, 67)

If i select an `article_id` , let’s say 61, I want to return:

```
article_id title    parent_article_id
-------------------------------------
61         mm       null
59         hgg      61
62         sef      61
67         wsr      61
```

That is the top of the node(61), and chidren/sibings (59, 62, 67)

If i select a `article_id` , let’s say 45, I want to return:

```
article_id title    parent_article_id
-------------------------------------
45         abc      null
```

There is no children/siblings, just the top of the node.

I’ve created a query that works, but I wonder if there is a better query to achieve what im looking for.

Here’s my query:

```
(
    SELECT
        ar.article_id,
        ar.parent_article_id parent_article_id,
        ar.title
    FROM
        article ar
    WHERE
        ar.article_id = 61
)
UNION (
    SELECT
        c.article_id,
        c.parent_article_id parent_article_id,
        c.title
    FROM
        article p
        JOIN article c ON p.parent_article_id = c.parent_article_id
            OR p.parent_article_id = c.article_id
            OR c.parent_article_id = p.article_id
    WHERE
        p.article_id = 61
)
ORDER BY
    parent_article_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a better query to achieve this, with [a subquery](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) masquerading as [an user-defined variable](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-variables/).

I always start simple, and first create a root query:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE article_id = 59;
```

This will only give me an article when the `article_id` itself is 59. This will clearly not do. We also need to find the children of the parent of this article, the siblings. So I first get the parent in a variable:

```
SET @parent_id := (SELECT parent_article_id
                   FROM article
                   WHERE article_id = 59);
```

I use a variable here because it is probably needed again later on. Note that the value of the variable is now 61.

Now we can easily get the siblings like this:

```
SELECT article_id 
FROM article
WHERE parent_article_id = @parent_id;
```

This will return articles [59, 62, 67] for article 59.

Looks good, but it is still not complete. Notice that you want a result of [59, 61, 62, 67] for article 59 and now we've only got [59 (twice), 62, 67]. What's missing?

Well, article 61 is missing, or what you call the "top node". It's not difficult to get this now:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE article_id = @parent_id;
```

This will result in 61 and completes our result.

Now I need to put the three queries together, and sort the result:

```
SET @child_id  := 59;
SET @parent_id := (SELECT parent_article_id
                   FROM article
                   WHERE article_id = @child_id);

SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE parent_article_id IN (@child_id, @parent_id) OR
      article_id IN (@child_id, @parent_id)
ORDER BY article_id;
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eddab1d/5

Notice how there's one extra query hidden in there:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE parent_article_id = @child_id;
```

This is for the case when the article is the "top node". In that case you still want the children.

Comment: It's even much faster than my solution and I had no idea that i could use variables in mysql. Thanks